# Extract numbers from a Cognito Form text field

Tags: cognito-forms

How would I extract the last three numbers of a text field (in this case is a passport number) of a Cognito Form?

Answer (score 1):

The help documentation for Text Functions is the best source of reference for any form of text manipulation in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com):

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/52/calculations/text-calculations

In this case, something like `=TextField.Substring(TextField.Length - 3)` should do the trick.